# Chrome Extension Folder Naming Convention

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying to determine if users on the network have a specific Chrome extension installed. I'd like to do this by identifying the install directory. I see that on Win 7 extensions appear here:

C:\Users\mmercer\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

Parent folders for extensions are named like this:

gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp

I tested and for a specific extension, I get the same parent folder name on any computer. At first, I thought it might be random.

I'd like to understand this naming convention. Does anyone know how these names are derived and why they appear like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the folder name is the [extension ID](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/packaging). I came across an article on stackoverflow detailing how to find an extension ID [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946325/chrome-extension-id-how-to-find-it).

The top answer details how the extension ID is in the Chrome Web Store URL that the extension has. The example used in the answer was [AdBlock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb).

[image]

In the example, it explained that since the AdBlock Plus URL is `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb`, the extension ID in this case is `cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb` (the last part of the URL). This is what the extension folder is named.

Comment: Excellent. I guess there is no guarantee it wont change as the software is updated, but this is as good an indicator as any. Thx!